# Node.js Tedious performance vs JDBC

Tags: sql-server, node.js, jdbc, query-performance, tedious

I am curious to know why `Tedious` (`node.js` implementation of TDS protocol) is much, much slower than JDBC. I ran few queries in same environment and here are the results:

```
Queries             JDBC      Node Tedious 
1000000 from tbl1   1.135 s   72.359 s
1000000 from tbl2   7.109 s   450.915 s
1000000 from tbl3   1.761 s   122.01 s
1000000 from tbl4   1.409 s   68.083 s 
1000000 from tbl5   1.553 s   69.083 s
```

**Note:** I used single connection in both environment and ran 1 query at a time. For Node, these timings are based on when tedious fires `DoneInProc` event, and for Java, I iterated over `ResultSet`.

Comment: Thank you @TallTed for editing